# Making a phone call with a laptop? (with a SIM card)

Tags: usb, mobile-phone

Is there such a device that would allow to connect a SIM card through USB and make an actual phone call? (no VOIP, not using a smartphone)

If yes, how is it called, what keywords should I use to get more info? Or do you have recommendations?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't such a thing officially available. Search keyword would be "USB 3G voice calling dongle."

There are some guides over the internet on how to "hack" data dongles to be able to call with it. See this:
https://www.journeybytes.com/2017/08/how-to-make-and-pick-calls-with-your.html?m=1
And this:
http://www.ruchirablog.com/unlock-voice-huawei-hspa/

Comment: This looks like, it could be what I'm looking for ?
https://www.befr.ebay.be/itm/4G-WIFI-LTE-USB-2-0-Dongle-Mobile-Broadband-Modem-SIM-Card-Signal-Voice-Call-SMS/192516033561

Comment: It definitely says it is. Now it needs to work as well...